# Limiting SQL Result

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a query where I am trying to get results from a table:

```
SELECT P.P_CODE, P.P_JEWELRYTYPE,P.p_catalog, P_AVAILABLE, P_RESERVED , p.p_catalog
FROM products P 
WHERE 
P.p_catalog IN (8796093383256,8796093252184,8796093317720,8796093121112,8796093186648);
```

I want a query where I can limit the number of results to 500 of each catalog type. How should I modify my query to achieve this?

Comment: where's the second table..?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan: I don't think there's actually a second table, probably a typo.

Comment: @einpoklum ok, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*, row_number() over (partition by catalog order by null) as seqnum
      from products p
     ) p
where p.seqnum <= 500;
```

You can put the `where` filtering in either the inner or outer query.

Answer (score 0):

Analytical function `row_number()` will work which will assign row numbers to each `p_catalog` so that you could filter on that condition in `WHERE` clause in an outer query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT 
    p.P_CODE, p.P_JEWELRYTYPE, p.p_catalog, p.P_AVAILABLE, p.P_RESERVED, p.p_catalog,
    row_number() over (partition by p.p_catalog) as rn
  FROM products p
  WHERE p.p_catalog IN (8796093383256,8796093252184,8796093317720,8796093121112,8796093186648)
) p
WHERE rn <= 500;
```